# Adding the Location programatically to a Tweet

Tags: android, twitter

I am Working with the twitter API's for Android and there is computation that happens in the cloud and based on that, the tweets are to be published. How do I add the location programatically when I tweet without the user having to input it again?

Cheers
VS

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: So far, there is some computation happening in the background. Now what I need to do is to set the long and lat values and pass them to twitter while posting a tweet. Is it possible? I am looking at options via twurl

Comment: Setting location is possible but there are multiple things that you need to keep in mind the user always has the option of removing the location, the lat-long should be available when you want to post and so on

Comment: So basically , the user inputs the location before the pre processing step and I get that location using the Google Places API. So I have the accurate lat and long. Any ideas on setting the location programatically?

Comment: have you checked [this](https://code.google.com/archive/p/socialauth-android/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to allow your twitter account to share location :
Connect on twitter.com with your account, go to your profile settings > Settings and privacy > Privacy and safety, check : Tweet with location, and save.

Then you can post with twurl and geolocation :

```
twurl -X POST -H api.twitter.com '/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=Testing twurl&lat=48.858334&lon=2.294415' | jq .
```